# JS - Вызов функции

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть две функции работы с Cookie.

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var r = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + name + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
  if (r) return r[2];
  else return "";
}
```

Вызов:

```
<script src="assets/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script>
setCookie("HistoryCookie", + getCookie("HistoryCookie") + 1);
</script>   
<script> document.write(getCookie("HistoryCookie")); </script>
```

Но, вызова не происходит и данные не выводятся. ( Пути к JS прописаны верно, проверял JS файл внутри HTML - тоже не работает).

Comment: Все работает http://jsbin.com/wepupekeru/edit?js,console приведение типов еще бы добавить parseInt когда получаешь значение куки.

Comment: Перепроверил на других браузерах, лишь в Firefox Работает нормально, вопрос закрыт.

Comment: до вас уже изобрели функции для работы с куками, используйте их, возможно поэтому у вас и работает только в фф https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="assets/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script>
  setCookie("HistoryCookie", + getCookie("HistoryCookie") + 1);
  document.write(getCookie("HistoryCookie")); /*(эта строка за рамками тэга script)*/
</script>
```

- обратите внимание на то что выводит консоль.
- подключайте `cookie.js` в хедере/или футере.
- плюс `setCookie` вызывать бы не по ходу загрузки страницы, а в `window.onload`

Comment: На счёт строки, это я не всё скопировал, там выходит:
<script> document.write(getCookie("HistoryCookie")); </script>

Answer (score 0):

Возможна причина области видимости двух скриптов. То есть внутренний скрип (который на странице) не видит объявленных функций внешнего скрипта.

```
<script src="assets/js/cookie.js"></script> // внешний скрипт
```

и внутренний скрипт который следует за ним, не видит что объявлено во внешнем скрипте.

```
<script>
setCookie("HistoryCookie", + getCookie("HistoryCookie") + 1);
</script>  // внутренний скрипт
```

получается что ,Вы, хотите вызвать функции которые находятся во внешнем скрипте, через внутрениий, но внутренний скрипт не знает о внешнем и наоборот.
Попробуйте весь JS переместить в 1 файл(допустим во внешний скрипт), и его подключить.
К примеру:

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
      document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
      var r = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + name + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
      if (r) return r[2];
      else return "";
    }

    setCookie("HistoryCookie", + getCookie("HistoryCookie") + 1);
    document.write(getCookie("HistoryCookie"));
```

вот так,  и подключить в через как один скрипт.

```
<script src="assets/js/cookie.js"></script>
```